# How do I change the display name in terminal (os x 10.6)

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-snow-leopard

I have used this script to install imageMagick:

Google: maddox magik-installer - its the first hit

My terminal name is a string of cryptic letters and numbers. See image here:

[image]

Keep in mind my computer name in the "Sharing" system preferences is localhost.

Any ideas how to change this?

Answer (score 1):

That's the hostname of the system as assigned by DHCP. Either set up a different hostname to use and override DHCP, or modiy `$PS1`.

Answer (score 0):

The imageMagick installation must have altered your .bashrc file. You'll want to edit it to something like `export PS1="\u@\h\w$ "` - specifically, you're setting the PS1 environment variable.

See http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/11/how-to-customize-your-terminal-prompt/ for more explanation and options.